# The script, which will take IP from the file etc/hosts

Tags: bash, shell-script, hosts

I write script, but this does not work. I need the script, which will take IP from the file etc/hosts. How to do it?

Script: (This does not work)

`host=www.example.com`

`ip=$(getent hosts "$host" | awk '{ print $1}')`

`echo $ip`

Comment: posting the exact same question again won't get you different answers.

Comment: Voting to delete this because it's the same question posted by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

If your given hostname at host filed is able to get name resolution then for sure you will get output.

Check are you able to ping to given hostname or not.

[image]

Comment: copy and paste text, don't post screenshots.

Comment: @cas that from a fresh VM , tools not yet installed.

Comment: @Raja If, instead "$host" I write www.example.com, it all works...